# ImportExcel for Dataset with Multiple tables

Tags: excel, powershell

I need to be able to create an Excel document with multiple tabs for a dataset with multiple results\data tables. I have a stored procedure with 3 selects in them, fairly simple ones pulling data from the sys tables in SQL Server.

Below is my script, where I am assuming there will be 5 tables, if there are more then it will be missed and if there are less and then the other tabs will be empty.

What's the best way to loop through the dataset and create the Excel document?

```
$SQLServer = 'SQL';
$Database = 'SomeDataWarehouse';
$sqlCommand = "EXEC dbo.Select_TestForPowershell";

$connectionString = "Server=$SQLServer;Database=$Database;Integrated Security=true"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sqlCommand, $connection)
$connection.Open()
$adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $command 
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataSet) > null
$connection.Close()

foreach ($table in $dataset.Tables) {
    Write-Host $table.TableName
    if ($($table.TableName) -eq 'table') {$Table1 = $table}
    if ($($table.TableName) -eq 'table1') {$Table2 = $table}
    if ($($table.TableName) -eq 'table2') {$Table3 = $table}
    if ($($table.TableName) -eq 'table3') {$Table4 = $table}
    if ($($table.TableName) -eq 'table4') {$Table5 = $table}
}

$DataToGather = @{
    table  = {$Table1}
    table1 = {$Table2}
    table2 = {$Table3}
    table3 = {$Table4}
    table4 = {$Table5}
}

#Export-MultipleExcelSheets -Show -AutoSize 'C:\Temp\Test.xlsx' $DataToGather
$DataToGather

$DataToGather.Clear()
```

Comment: If your script works you're better off posting this question to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) otherwise what's not working as expected?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion @LotPings, will log there for review.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Ansgar Wiechers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by using the below code.

```
$sqlCommand = @"
SELECT * FROM SalesLT.Address
SELECT * FROM SalesLT.Customer
SELECT * FROM SalesLT.CustomerAddress
SELECT * FROM SalesLT.Product
SELECT * FROM SalesLT.ProductCategory
SELECT * FROM SalesLT.ProductDescription
SELECT * FROM SalesLT.ProductModel
"@

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
$command = New-Object System.Data.Sqlclient.Sqlcommand($sqlCommand, $connection)
$connection.Open()
$adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.SqlDataAdapter $command
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$null=$adapter.Fill($dataSet) 
$connection.Close()

$xlfile = "$env:TEMP\tables.xlsx"
rm $xlfile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$count=1
foreach($table in $dataset.Tables) {
    $name = "Table$($count)"
    $table| Export-Excel $xlfile -WorksheetName $name -AutoSize -TableName $name
    $count+=1
}

Invoke-Item $xlfile
```

Comment: Old answer, but dataset stuff can just be this:

$adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.SqlDataAdapter $sqlCommand,$connectionString;
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;
$null=$adapter.Fill($dataSet);
$null=$dataset.Dispose();

If you have to have a dataset anyway, it will open the connection for you and disposing of it will close it. Sorry for formatting, but I didn't think this warranted another answer, but I thought I'd leave a comment for other dataset users. =)